# MYSQL delete all rows, but the same query on select return only 3 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I can't understand why the same query for select and delete have different behavior.
I need to delete all rows except 5 newest rows.
I know my solution for this task is no good, but my question is about why MySQL no delete the same rows, that return select for the same query clause

see code

```sql
drop table if exists tbl;
create table tbl
(
    id         serial,
    cal        date COMMENT 'some column',
    created_at datetime default NOW()
);

insert into tbl
values
       (default, '2018-07-15', '2018-07-15 12:00'),
       (default, '2018-07-16', '2018-07-16 12:00'),
       (default, '2018-07-17', '2018-07-17 12:00'),
       (default, '2018-07-18', '2018-07-18 12:00'),
       (default, '2018-08-01', '2018-08-01 12:00'),
       (default, '2018-08-04', '2018-08-04 12:00'),
       (default, '2018-08-16', '2018-08-16 12:00'),
       (default, '2018-08-17', '2018-08-17 12:00');

  select *
  from tbl;

    #     +----+------------+---------------------+
    #     | id | cal        | created_at          |
    #     +----+------------+---------------------+
    #     | 1  | 2018-07-15 | 2018-07-15 12:00:00 |
    #     | 2  | 2018-07-16 | 2018-07-16 12:00:00 |
    #     | 3  | 2018-07-17 | 2018-07-17 12:00:00 |
    #     | 4  | 2018-07-18 | 2018-07-18 12:00:00 |
    #     | 5  | 2018-08-01 | 2018-08-01 12:00:00 |
    #     | 6  | 2018-08-04 | 2018-08-04 12:00:00 |
    #     | 7  | 2018-08-16 | 2018-08-16 12:00:00 |
    #     | 8  | 2018-08-17 | 2018-08-17 12:00:00 |
    #     +----+------------+---------------------+
```

now I need delete rows with id 1,2,3

```sql
SET @row_number = 0;
select *
from tbl
where tbl.id in (
    select T.id
    from (SELECT (@row_number := @row_number + 1) as num, tbl.id
          from tbl
          order by created_at desc
         ) as T
    where T.num > 5);


# +----+------------+---------------------+
# | id | cal        | created_at          |
# +----+------------+---------------------+
# | 3  | 2018-07-17 | 2018-07-17 12:00:00 |
# | 2  | 2018-07-16 | 2018-07-16 12:00:00 |
# | 1  | 2018-07-15 | 2018-07-15 12:00:00 |
# +----+------------+---------------------+
```

Now I use delete operation

```
SET @row_number = 0;
delete
from tbl
where tbl.id in (
    select T.id
    from (SELECT (@row_number := @row_number + 1) as num, tbl.id
          from tbl
          order by created_at desc
         ) as T
    where T.num > 5);

select * from tbl; # <-- result empty
# +----+-----+------------+
# | id | cal | created_at |
# +----+-----+------------+
```

I cry;

Comment: Why do you use `@row_number` since there is `id`?

Comment: The ID may differ from row_number, for example ID can start with 1000...

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: I would avoid updating user variables in queries.   When they are updated will depend on the query plan.  In this case, IN-subqueries in SELECT queries will be converted to semijoin while in single table DELETE, they will not.  You may get same query plan if you use multi-table DELETE syntax (see http://oysteing.blogspot.com/2014/07/a-multi-table-trick-to-speed-up-single.html), but instead I suggest you should look into windows functions introduced in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: thanks, @oysteing, I was try like you wrote:  `DELETE part FROM part
WHERE p_partkey IN ...`  It helps. I was wondered, sadly my knowledge is not sufficient.

Comment: I needed to understand the difference, thanks you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try doing a delete limit join here:

```
DELETE t1
FROM tbl t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM tbl
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    LIMIT 5
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
    t2.id IS NULL;
```

The idea behind this anti-join is that we will delete any record which does *not* match to one of the first five records, as ordered descending by the `created_at` column.

Note that we can't use a `WHERE IN` query here, because MySQL will return the dreaded error message that `LIMIT` is not yet supported in this version.

Answer (score 1):

Get the highest ID to delete using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`:

```
set @last_id_to_delete = (
  select id
  from tbl
  order by id desc
  limit 1
  offset 5
);
```

Then delete all rows with ID equal or smaller than the obove value:

```
delete tbl
from tbl
where id <= @last_id_to_delete;
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hnp38JAfCFeyVpNdyWbpdW/0)

You can combine the two queries into one. Either with a subquery in the WHERE clause:

```
delete tbl
from tbl
where id <= (select id from(
  select id
  from tbl
  order by id desc
  limit 1
  offset 5
)x);
```

(Note that you need to wrap the subquery result into a derived table, to avoid the error: "You can't specify target table 'tbl' for update in FROM clause".)

[db-fidle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xa7YZ2hJAKyM5RvAiirFK/0)

or by joining with a single-row subquery:

```
delete t
from tbl t
join (
  select id as last_id_to_delete
  from tbl
  order by id desc
  limit 1
  offset 5
) x on t.id <= x.last_id_to_delete;
```

[db-fidle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9H1yhePqQQXFCkXQHCUxiF/0)